# How could I send an initial response (res.send or res.write) to the client via endpoint, then via the the same endpoint, send an image to the client

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, response

I am creating an image-processing-API that takes an image and data from the user via URL (query string) then processes this image, then sends it back to the user.
her's how the code look like:

```
export const writeFile = async (width: number, height: number, pathToFullImage: string, pathToThumbImage: string): Promise<void> => {
try {
    //process the image
    let image = await sharp(`${pathToFullImage}.jpeg`).resize(width, height).jpeg().toBuffer();
    fs.writeFile(`${pathToThumbImage}.jpeg`, image);
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error from async func in writeFile  ${error}`)
}
```

};

```
export const readFile = (res: express.Response, pathToThumbImage: string) =>{
try {
    res.sendFile(`${pathToThumbImage}.jpeg`);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error from async func in readFile ${error}`)
}
```

}

```
mainEndpoint.get('/api', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) : void=>{
res.write("API route");

//get the query string from url to be used 
const data: ParsedQs = req.query;

//get the width and the height from 'data' object
let filename = data.filename as string;
let width: number = parseInt(data.width as string);
let height: number = parseInt(data.height as string);

//call the function
writeFile(width, height, pathToFullImage, pathToThumbImage);

//call the readFile function 
// If we didnt use setTimeout, the endpoint will try to read before the file is even written, so to solve this problem, use setTimeOut to make the reading process lag after the writing in the event loop. 
setTimeout(()=>readFile(res, pathToThumbImage), 100);

console.log(data);

res.end();
```

})

***How the code works:***

**First:** I get the query string, process them in 'mainEndpoint'     **second:** send them to 'writeFile' to precess image an save it in the target folder       **third:** pass them to 'readFile' to use 'res.sendFile' to sen them to the client

***The problem is:***
when I try to send an initial response with 'res.write' , 'readFile' doesn't send the image?

***How could I make the endpoint send the initial response and the image?***  Altough every thing works if I didn't send the initial response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `await` the `writeFile` call.  You won't have to setTimeout then.

```js
//call the function
await writeFile(width, height, pathToFullImage, pathToThumbImage);

//call the readFile function 
setTimeout(()=>readFile(res, pathToThumbImage), 100);
```

and also await in `writeFile`.

```js
const writeFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)
await writeFilePromise(`${pathToThumbImage}.jpeg`, image);
```

Finally, don't call this at all, because you can't mix your return values of a string, and then a file.

```
res.write("API route");
```

Comment: Thanks for this new info. but the problem is, I am using Jasmine for unit testing and I'm testing this endpoint if it returns 200 ok status, so If I didn't send an initial response with either 'res.send' or 'res.write' this whole endpoint will fail in my unit testing because it doesn't return this initial response, how can I solve this?